# Trouble with apt — "The list of sources could not be read"

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-sources

I am using Ubuntu **20.04.3 LTS**.

```
~ sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal: /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

As a total newbie, I have no idea what to do.  Any guidance would be most appreciated. Hopefully, a similar question has been asked in the past and one of you can kindly link to it. My search for duplicates was not very successful.

Comment: https://apt.kitware.com/ : If you really think you still need this cmake repo, please run the script `kitware-archive.sh`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you.  If I recall correctly, I had the same error message when I tried to run the script `kitware-archive.sh`. Eventually, I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by commenting the following line in file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal
```